selenium find element by xpath and child tag not working
For the DOM
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="refreshIcon refreshFiling">
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="CFRefresh('CFanncEquity')"><img src="/assets/images/refresh-icon.svg" alt="Refresh" title="Refresh">Refresh</a>
   </div>
</div>

With my Python selenium code
  refresh_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="refreshIcon"]/a')

I'm getting
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="refreshIcon"]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.126); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

Why?

Share the HTML in the text format not image. Read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Replaced the image with text.

Try this XPath expression - //div[@class='refreshIcon refreshFiling']//a

refreshIcon is not the whole class, it is just part of the class.

that worked, Thanks.

According to the DOM you gave, the xpath should be:
//div[contains(@class, "refreshIcon")]/a

or
//div[@class="refreshIcon refreshFiling"]/a

